# Approve userpoints programmatically

Tags: rules, userpoints

I grant my users userpoints with pending status, for some actions on my site.

I want to automatically approve the points after 2 weeks. Is there a function to change the status of the points?

Also I want to cancel the points if the users submit a form.

Comment: Are you using Drupal 7? Take a look at documentation - http://api.worldempire.ch/api/userpoints/userpoints_contrib-7.x-1.x!userpoints_autoapprove!userpoints_autoapprove.module/7-1